# What should be done with questions that give the link for the code instead of showing it?

Tags: support, faq, questions

There are some questions that don't show the code for which the question is being asked, but give a link to the code.

What should be done with these questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question should contain the relevant parts that allow to answer it. If the code is linked, instead of being shown in the question, the question would not be helpful to future readers, when the link is not anymore accessible.

Those questions should be edited to include the code, or the part of the code that is relevant for the question. This should be done even if the question refers the code shown in a blog, such as in "I found this code on [link to the blog]; I used it, but it doesn't work for me."
If the link doesn't work anymore, flag (or vote to close) the question as being too localized ("flag" > "it doesn't belong here" > "too localized").

The same is true for questions linking an external image, where the image is necessary to understand the question, such as in "I want to implement the feature shown in this page [link to the screenshot]. Is there a module that implements something similar?"